# Prove by induction that no terms in FOL of arithmetic begins or ends with 2 plus signs (++)

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

Prove by induction that no terms in FOL of arithmetic begins or ends with 2 plus signs (++)

I have no idea how to start this proof, can someone help me?

Comment: As with any proof by induction, you first must prove that it holds for the base case. Then, you define the recursive case (maybe in this scenario, you have a FOL term that is a composition of other FOL terms?), and you show that it can't hold there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

You have to start with the *formal* definition of *term* in [first order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic):

> a *variable* or the (individual) *constant* **0**;

this will be the *basis* for induction on the *lenght* of the term: no occurrence of **+** and thus no two consecutive *plus*.

Or:

> the *function* symbol **S** followed by a *term* **t** to get the new term **S(t)**: no new occurrence of **+**.

In this case the *induction hypotheses* is that **t** satisfies the condition; thus, also **St** does.

Or:

> **(s+t)** or **(s . t)**, where **s** and **t** are *terms*.

In this case the *induction hypotheses* is that both **s** and **t** satisfy the condition, and we have to prove that also **(s+t)** and **(s . t)** do.